# Hash of two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table, with 5 columns in it:

```
id bigint
name varchar
description varchar
slug
```

Can I get MySQL to automatically generate the value of slug as a 256 Bit Hash of name+description?

I am now using PHP to generate an SHA256 value of the slug prior to saving it.

## Edit:

By automatic, I mean see if it's possible to change the default value of the slug field, to be a computed field that's the sha256 of name+description.

I already know how to create it as part of an insert operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 supports [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) so you can define an expression, and it will be updated automatically for every row you insert or update.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  slug varchar(64) AS (SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256)) STORED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If you use an earlier version of MySQL, you could do this with [TRIGGERs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER MySlugIns BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW SET slug = SHA2(CONCAT(name, description));

CREATE TRIGGER MySlugUpd BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW SET slug = SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I'm looking for. Does TRIGGER run on MySQL 5.7 as well? I want to use Mysql 5.6 for now (incompatibilities with the Rails MySQL Gem), but would like to use something that's not going to break when I move to 5.7

Comment: Yes, triggers are still supported on MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Ah, so that's "automatic". Seems more resource intensive than just doing it in PHP.

Comment: @showdev, there is a cost to executing triggers on INSERT or UPDATE. It's greater than zero cost, but it's on the same order of magnitude as an INSERT or UPDATE that updates an index. People do that in databases regularly.

Comment: Fair enough. A matter of preference, I suppose. Looks like it works for the OP's context.

Comment: I don't have the option of executing a statement. Users are uploading the value through a spreadsheet with only the two values for name and description

Comment: Yes, there's an advantage to managing the automatic hashing in the database, if there are different applications or clients inserting data and you can't control them all.

Comment: If someone ever use this answer, note that there is an error in this syntax. NOT NULL part goes at the end of the column generation (so it must be written after STORED)

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the syntax in the answer above.

Comment: For MariaDb (10.1.48) the syntax must be `slug varchar(64) AS (SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256)) PERSISTENT` (can't use NOT NULL and must use PERSISTENT instead of STORED). At least thats how I got it working on our server.

Comment: @DevZe, I think MariaDB is now a totally different database implementation from MySQL. They have many examples of different syntax to do similar tasks.

Comment: @BillKarwin I would not say TOTALLY different. In fact, that was the first time I encountered a problem that I couldn't solve with the "mysql solution". (Thats why I wrote this comment). I might have to change this habit, but I am always searching for "mysql <my problem>" (and we are using MariaDb for years). 
Thanks for the heads up, never the less!

Comment: @DevZe, By that standard, neither MySQL nor MariaDB are TOTALLY different from most other brands of SQL database, like Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, or Informix. But what is true is that you can't assume any given SQL query or command will work the same on any of them, without reviewing documentation carefully and testing it.

Comment: I don't like that `SHA2(CONCAT('foo', 'bar'), 256)` and `SHA2(CONCAT('f', 'oobar'), 256)` produce the same hash.  For that reason, I recommend using `SHA2(JSON_OBJECT(name, description), 256)`.

Comment: @CourtneyMiles, The problem statement didn't say it needed to be unique.

Answer (score 7):

Beware that concat returns NULL if *any one* column in the input is NULL. So, to hash in a null-safe way, use `concat_ws`. For example:

```
select md5(concat_ws('', col_1, .. , col_n));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use MySQL's [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to combine the two values and [`SHA2()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) to generate a 256 bit hash.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`,`description`,`slug`)
     VALUES ('Fred','A Person',SHA2(CONCAT(`name`,`description`),256));

SELECT * FROM `mytable`
```

OUTPUT:

```
COLUMN        VALUE
id            1
name          Fred
description   A Person
slug          ea76b5b09b0e004781b569f88fc8434fe25ae3ad17807904cfb975a3be71bd89
```

Try it on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01eaaa/1).

Comment: My question is "Can I get MySQL to automatically generate". Per my question, I'm already using PHP to insert the slug in.

Comment: Define "automatically". My SQL code generates a third hash value from the two values inserted.

Comment: Automatic, as in I can define a field as timestamp, and set the default to generate a timestamp automatically. Your code, just like mine, must compute the slug manually, and then assign it as a value, prior to inserting.

Comment: No. Notice that I'm *not* providing a hashed slug value to the `INSERT` statement. I'm only providing the "name" and "description". Do you want the hash to be generated without mentioning it in the `INSERT` statement at all? I don't think there's a specific data type for automatic hashing that would be equivalent to `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: This is still a manually generated value, and not a "default" value. Like I said, I'm already doing this. See my edit

Comment: I don't see how its "manual", but I guess we have different definitions. You said you're doing it with PHP. My example doesn't use any PHP. I guess you're looking for a specific [data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) that populates with a hash. Without a way to specify *what* is being hashed, that doesn't seem logical.