# Created table with generated columns throw an error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to build my table in MySQL following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38732185/hash-of-two-columns-in-mysql) answer. Hower i keep getting errors in MySQL even launching the same query used as example in the answer

this query is from documentation and works correctly

```
CREATE TABLE triangle (
  sidea DOUBLE,
  sideb DOUBLE,
  sidec DOUBLE AS (SQRT(sidea * sidea + sideb * sideb)) stored
);
```

this query comes from the answer i've linked and it gives me an error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  description varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  slug text NOT NULL AS (SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

this is the query i am trying to execute based on the answer which is giving me also an error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  first VARCHAR(104) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  second DATETIME NULL,
  third DATETIME NULL,
  fourth VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  table_key varchar(64) NOT NULL AS (SHA2(concat_ws(',',first, second, third, fourth), 256)) stored unique,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (first));
```

can you help me figuring out why it's not working?

Note that `SHA2(concat_ws(',',first, second, third, fourth), 256)` this works in a normal select statement

**EDIT**

this is the error i am getting

```
Query execution failed

Reason:

Errore SQL [1064] [42000]: (conn:28) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS (SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256) STORED,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)

) DEFAULT ' at line 5
Query is : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (

  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  description varchar(50) NOT NULL,

  slug text NOT NULL AS (SHA2(CONCAT(name, description), 256) STORED,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)

) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide the error what you got

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev edited the question with the error i get on the second query (the one from the answer i've linked)

Comment: Alter datatype from TEXT to BINARY() with proper length.

Comment: @Akina it didn't worked

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Comment: `STORED UNIQUE NOT NULL` seems to be OK in MySQL but not MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames SHA2 won't work on Maria unless you set SSL. I had the same problem. I couldn't figure out how to fix it, and adopted another solution

Comment: @DanieleSartori - You can move the Accepted Checkmark to a different Answer.

Comment: @DanieleSartori - SHA2 may be needed for SSL, but I don't think SSL needs to be used in order to use the SHA2 function.

Comment: @RickJames it's written in MariaDB documentation for SHA2 statement. Also the guy technically answered my question since i did a mistake in my query and he corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `NOT NULL` after the `AS` part (computed column definition) of the column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  first VARCHAR(104) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',  
  second DATETIME NULL,
  third DATETIME NULL,
  fourth VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  table_key varchar(64) AS (SHA2(concat_ws(',',first, second, third, fourth), 256)) stored unique NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (first)
);
```

Also have a look at the [official document of `CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). There you can find the description of the datatype syntax. The definition of the computed column is part of the datatype.